# read from file to memory in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to store numbers 10 to 20 in address 50 to 60 in memory. I wrote a system module that contains CPU and memory. then added a system test bench that takes care of system module instantiation, clock, reset.

I should write a .txt file to write addresses and readmemb in memory to read from it.

how should I change my memory module ? what should the .txt file contain?

memory module:

```
module Memory (inbus, outbus, addr,rd_mem, wr_mem);

    input [5:0] addr;
    input [7:0] inbus;
    input rd_mem, wr_mem;  

    output [7:0] outbus;

    reg [7:0] mem [0:63];

    assign outbus = rd_mem ? mem [addr] : 8'bz;
    always @ (wr_mem)
        if (wr_mem == 1) mem [addr] <= inbus;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Your .txt file should contain the data, readmemb means each line in the .txt file is in binary whereas readmemh means each line in the .txt file is in hexadecimal.

```
//.txt file snippet, adding only 6 location (6 lines in the txt file), change/add data as per requirement, each line has hex data.

23
63 
b3
23
73
b3

//Add this in your code
initial
 $readmemh("data.txt",mem); //Assuming name of txt is data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Some synthesizers (e.g. ISE from Xilinx) will reject a partial initialization, so even if you only need addresses 50 to 60 to have a certain value, you have to ensure that all your memory is initialized. This can be solved by using a loop to initialize all memory cells to 0, then overwriting some of them with values from a external file, like this:

```
module Memory (inbus, outbus, addr,rd_mem, wr_mem);

input [5:0] addr;
input [7:0] inbus;
input rd_mem, wr_mem;  

output [7:0] outbus;

reg [7:0] mem [0:63];

////////////// ADD THIS ////////////////////////////
integer i;
initial begin
  for (i=0; i<=63; i=i+1)
    mem[i] = 8'h00;
  $readmemh ("memory.txt", mem, 50, 60);
end
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

assign outbus = rd_mem ? mem [addr] : 8'bz;
always @ (wr_mem)
    if (wr_mem == 1) mem [addr] <= inbus;
endmodule
```

With memory.txt containing 11 values (10 to 20) in hexadecimal, one by line, like this:

```
0a
0b
0c
0d
0e
0f
10
11
12
13
14
```

Alternatively, you can avoid using a external file if all you need is to store consecutively values to memory. Just replace the $readmemh.... with another loop, like this:

```
for (i=50; i<=60; i=i+1)
  mem[i] = i-40;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you try to use $readmemb to read, the memfile.txt file should be

```
00010101
00010110
00010111
00011000
00011001
...
```

and Memory module should be

```
module Memory (inbus, outbus, addr,rd_mem, wr_mem);

input [5:0] addr;
input [7:0] inbus;
input rd_mem, wr_mem;  

output [7:0] outbus;

reg [7:0] mem [0:63];

// here is mem read data from file
initial begin
    $readmemb("./memfile.txt",mem,50,60);
end
// here is read part end

assign outbus = rd_mem ? mem [addr] : 8'bz;
always @ (wr_mem)
    if (wr_mem == 1) mem [addr] <= inbus;
endmodule
```